# What does “cantilever” stand for in the line, “baseball environment obsessed with the cantilever between pitcher and hitter?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In the New York Times’ (August 5) article titled, “How A-Rod doesn’t add up,” Doug Glanville, ex-outfielder for the Philadelphia Phillies, Chicago Cubs and Texas Rangers tells:
http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/08/05/how-a-rod-doesnt-add-up/?hp

> “Performance-enhancing drugs thrive in a baseball environment obsessed
>   with the **cantilever between pitcher and hitter**, opportunity and
>   failure, the home run and the glove man, the quantitative and the
>   qualitative. With all of this balance, numbers often tip the scale,
>   and when it’s in a player’s interest to use numbers to gain value, he
>   will do so, especially if his contract depends on it.”

I was drawn to the usage of ‘cantilever’ in the phrase, “obsessed with the cantilever between pitcher and hitter, opportunity and failure ...”

I understand ‘cantilever’ is a projecting beam or structure supported at only one end like a porch supported by steel cantilevers, and it is used figuratively in the above message, but my poor imagination doesn’t go any further.

What does “cantilever between A and B" in opposing position mean? Does it have something to do with conflicting balance, or competing tactics? Could you paraphrase “cantilever” in a plain word?

Comment: I think he is considering the balance beam in a pair of scales.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think he is considering/confused by the balance beam in a pair of scales like below.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking they meant _fulcrum._

Comment: Drat THAT was the word **I** was looking for :) - it is the point where the balance beam is turning about.

Comment: Is it something like a tipping point?

Comment: The fulcrum, yes. But I think the author really was thinking about the two ends of the balancing beam, one being a, the other b and something upsetting the balance

Comment: I asked him to join the discussion :)